# How do you set a default output-directory?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, miktex, compiling, windows

I use to put all files that are generated by compiler in a folder called `build` with the instruction

`pdflatex -output-directory=build myfile.tex`

How do I set this folder as *default* so I wouldn't need to write it every time I compile?

I tried to edit the pdfconfig file following the [documentation reference of MikTeX .ini](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex.ini.html).

```
[TeXandFriends]
    ;; Create the output directory if '--output-directory=DIR'
    ;; refers to a non-existing directory.
    CreateOutputDirectory = build
```

However it only states the directory to be created when the directory input of the option `--output-directory` does not exist.

I didn't find any way of setting a default value for `--output-directory` option, so I would thank any orientation with this.

Comment: @Marijn Second answer (write wrapper) works (of course it does.), first answer (set texmf.cnf) doesn't. – so they're not exact duplicate (if "in theory" there's some specific way to override output-directory apart from this method, it would not be applicable to the other question which specifically asks for file-line-error)

Comment: It seems there's no such config item or environment variable. (`TEXMFOUTPUT` is only used when the default or specified output directory is not writable.) How about defining a command alias?

Comment: @Marjin In general the answer is there, but I was looking for an specific answer. Is there any command to setup that property directly?

Comment: @user202729 I assumed _all_ command line flags could be set through texmf.cnf (therefore I suggested the duplicate) but apparently this is not the case.

Comment: Which operating system? (writing shell script is not cross platform.) (if you still can't write yourself for some reason.)

Comment: @user202729 MikTeX Windows.

Comment: How to create shell script isn't really TeX-related, but you can start with something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181709/ddg#5181873  (or search for something like "create custom commands in Windows command-line")

Comment: @user202729 I found kind of wired that there is no simple way to setup this property directly in MikTeX.

Comment: typically pdflatex is called through some menu or shortcut in your editor, and there you always can add such default options.

Comment: @SDEscobedo MikTeX is a distribution, not a particular program. // If you mean you can't modify the pdflatex executable to do what you want by default, it kind of make sense because otherwise it will break *other* scripts/programs that depends on pdflatex. // Compare, you can't set `echo` to add `-n` by default, or `ls` to add `--color=auto` by default either without defining an alias (... if you use some bash)

Comment: @user202729 No, I mean that there should be a command to set this property default. I found however that you can use `--set-config-value=[section]valuename=value` to change a value in the `.ini` file. However the MikTeX documentation gives not much details about the variable names. I am trying to figure it out.